# Google.Apis assembly reference error

Tags: .net, api, authentication, sharepoint, google-api

I have created a custom log in page for an on premise SharePoint 2013 site. I have then added logic to use Google's authentication to log in to the SharePoint site. When I build the project I am getting this error:

```
error CS0012: The type 'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.8.1.31687, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I have added this reference. Also I have added the reference to my GAC. When I double click the error it takes me to this part of the code:

```
private PlusService ps = null;
```

but I do not get any red marks or errors on the line in the code, only in the output window. I have used the code Google gives as a sample and I have downloaded the api references from nuget as Google suggests. Does anyone have any ideas or has anyone come across this before?